# Design a function so that it can be used as CLI (using click) and python modules directly

Tags: python, python-click

I am searching a design through which same python function can be exposed to other modules as well as a CLI created using click module.

I saw many posts available for the same but my requirement is little different.

I have a command as:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--times', default=10)
def print_hello(times):
    _print_hello(times)
    

def _print_hello(times):
    pass
```

Here main logic to print something is written in _print_hello function which is fine.

If I wanted to call print_hello method from a function defined in other modules then it would be a hectic task for the caller.

Do we have any easy way or good pattern because I have more than 20 CLI APIs which I need to expose as python API as well?

Comment: Please ask only on question per question.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean, how to make a function accept one or more arguments ? Give each argument a default value:

```py
def print_func(param1, param2=None, param3=None, param4=None, param5=None):
    print(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)

print_func()
print_func(1)
print_func(1, 2)
print_func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: print_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param1'

1 None None None None

1 2 None None None

1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: No, because this print_func is a cli command too. How we would handle cli case with *args?

Comment: @AbhayVerma i edited my answer, does it now do what you need ?